# An ant is walking up a hill. at what x does he see the blade of grass.

Tags: derivatives, recurrence-relations, graphing-functions

've been working on this problem with Mathematica and by hand-help with either would be fantastic. The blade of grass is given by the line segment from (32,1/5) and (32,8). The 2D hill is given by f(x)=(1/16 x^2 - 2 x + 80)/(1/16 x^2 - 2 x + 20)^2

I am struggling to figure out how to set the equations so that I can solve the point on the hill line, especially because I have to qualify that the other point on the line (which slope equal to f'(x)) must intersect only between y=1/5-8 AND not interest h(x) again (which defines the hill).
Any help, detailed or theoretical is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the point $x$ is the point on the hill where the ant can see the top of the blade of grass.  Plugging $x$ into $h(x)$ you can get the $y$ value.

Then you can set up an equation for the slope of $h(x)$ at $x$ using the derivative of $h(x)$ and an equation of the line from that point to the top of the blade of grass using $\frac{y-y}{x-x}$ as its slope.  And these two slopes should be equal.

EDIT: to clarify, i think the line equation should be the line that goes through our $(x,y)$ on the hill, and the point $(32,8)$.  I am imagining a big arm hinged at one end at $(32,8)$ and allowed to drop onto the hill.  And from the characteristics of the $h(x)$ I think there is only one point in the domain we are interested in that will have the same slope as that line will, since it is decreasing over that domain.

[image]

Comment: Right! I've been trying that, but I can't seem to figure out how you ensure that the derivative of h(x), the tangent line, will not intersect h(x) again (for the ant cannot see through the hill)

Comment: So you're saying that the ant will see the very top of the blade of the grass no matter what? the tangent line will approach from the top - that makes it easier not having it be a range of points

Comment: I think it will involve a second derivative test and see that the slope of the hill is always decreasing as you move in the positive $x$ direction in the domain we are interested in.

Comment: Let me think about it a bit.  Somebody smarter might come in and give a better answer in the meantime...

Comment: Oh, yes that would make sense. thanks!

Comment: Even though the blade of grass will be much taller than the hill?

Comment: Yes.  I'm guessing the $x$ will be slightly less than where the max of $h(x)$ is.

Comment: It intersects the blade of grass at x=14.9 or so, which is before the max height of the hill, because the blade of grass is much higher.